# manage.py command returns help text

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-manage.py

I have a problem with `manage.py` - it returns 'help' instead of creating an app. I'm quite new in Django so it could be obvious.

I've created a **Django** project using **PyCharm**.

```
New Project../Django../Projct
```

So **PyCharm** created a directory called `Projct` which looks like:

```
Projct/
    Projct/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    Templates/
    manage.py
```

Now, I want to start on project so I change a name of the `SQLite` database and do this command:

...PycharmProjects/Projct/manage.py startapp projct

Cmd returns:

```
Available subcommands

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runfcgi
    shell
    showmigrations
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver
```

I've already tried `syncdb` and it returns the same list.

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following in Pycharm `Ctrl+Alt+R`, when the new window comes up, type in `runserver` and hit enter.